# How to use newrelic exporter with nestjs opentelemetry?

Tags: nestjs, newrelic, open-telemetry

I would like to send dimensional metrics to New Relic from my NestJS application. I want to utilize opentelemetry for that. Is it possible to integrate new relic exporter with nestjs-opentelemetry?

I tried to look at the official documentation from nestjs-opentelemetry and list of official exporters. Do not see anything besides zipkin and jaeger.

Comment: Maybe this will help, you can use a generic exporter: https://newrelic.com/blog/how-to-relic/opentelemetry-full-stack-javascript